# Edit attribute table for shapefiles in folders and subfolders with arcpy?

Tags: python, arcpy, layers, attribute-table

Continuously to [Merge shapefiles in folders and subfolders with arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/131689/merge-shapefiles-in-folders-and-subfolders-with-arcpy) I try to edit attribute table for 20 shapefiles that spread in big a folder and are divided to a lot of sub folders. All shapefiles are called "migrashim" and the name of the filed that i want to change is "structuretype". I try this code:

```
import arcpy,os,sys,string,fnmatch,arcpy.mapping
from arcpy import env

rootPath = r"C:\Project\layers"
pattern = 'migrashim.shp'
features = arcpy.UpdateCursor(r"C:\Project\layers\*.shp")
counter = 0
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rootPath):
    for filename in files:
        if filename == "migrashim.shp":
            for feature in features:
                if feature.structuretype == 3:
                feature.structuretype = 4
                features.updateRow(feature)
        counter = counter + 1
print 'edit'
print counter
del feature,features
```

but i got an error:

```
IOError: "C:\Project\layers\migrashim.shp" does not exist
```

What wrong with my code?

Comment: I recommend investigating arcpy.mapping (in particular ListLayers) and arcpy.da.Walk both here and in the ArcGIS Help.

Comment: Which version of ArcGIS are you using?

Comment: I'm using arcview 10.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use below code--

If you have access to "Data Access Module"

```
import arcpy,os,sys
pattern = 'fish_46.shp'
folder = 'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\delete'## root folder
field = 'Id' ## your field where calculation to be applied
files_process = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\delete'):
    for filenames in files:
        if filenames == pattern:
            files_process.append(os.path.join(root, filenames))

for i in files_process:
    curU = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(i,field)
    for row in curU:
        row[0]=1 ##Any expression you want
        curU.updateRow(row)
del curU
```

**EDIT**

If you do not have access to "Data Access Module"

```
import arcpy,os,sys
pattern = 'fish_46.shp'
folder = 'C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\delete'## root folder
field = 'Id' ## your field where calculation to be applied
files_process = []
for root,dirs,files in os.walk('C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop\delete'):
    for filenames in files:
        if filenames == pattern:
            files_process.append(os.path.join(root, filenames))

for i in files_process:
    curU = arcpy.UpdateCursor(i)
    for row in curU:
        row.setValue(field, 500)##Any expression you want
        curU.updateRow(row)
del curU
```

Comment: i get an error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 18: invalid continuation byte

Comment: I checked the code right now and it's working perfectly.Please confirm there is no non-ASCII chars in the scope this script gets through and please do not cut-copy-paste code into the IDE from ms-word, notepad etc. I found some times those text processors convert simple inverted commas into bizarre non-unicode/ascii chars and again i am to type them manually.

Comment: i get an error: File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\mixins.py", line 16, in <module>
    curU = arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(i,field)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'da'   i need help please

Comment: Please try latter  code..

Comment: Use the later added, i mean second block, i mean lowest code after the word EDIT in my answer....................

Comment: i still got the same error. my python don't work any more